# How to rename multiple files to their contents' MD5 sum?

Tags: scripting, rename, hashsum

I would like to rename some files to their contents' MD5 sum; for example, if file `foo` is empty, it should be renamed to `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.

Does it have to be script or can I use something like the `rename` tool?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `md5sum /dev/null`? Md5sum's output format varies depending on the OS.

Comment: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /dev/null

Comment: Do you want to rename only  files in the current dir or recursively rename all files ?

Comment: @don_crissti Depends.

Comment: :) in that case the answer to your question is: _Depends_.

Comment: @don_crissti :D Okay, let's start with current dir.

Comment: @don_crissti: That's an example, which I think was sorely missing (the question, as originally worded, could have been interpreted as meaning "append hex representation of MD5 to file name", or in a bunch of other ways). Perhaps it would have been cleaner to choose a more arbitrary sum as an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glenn's answer is good; here's a refinement for multiple files:

```
md5sum file1 file2 file3 | # or *.txt, or whatever
    while read -r sum filename; do
        mv -v "$filename" "$sum"
    done
```

If you're generating files with `find` or similar, you can replace the `md5sum` invocation with something like `find . <options> -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum` (with the output also piped into the shell loop).

This is taking the output of `md5sum`, which consists of multiple lines with a sum and then the file it corresponds to, and piping it into a shell loop which reads each line and issues a `mv` command that renames the file from the original name to the sum. Any files with identical sums will be overwritten; however, barring unusual circumstances (like if you're playing around with md5 hash collisions), that will mean they had the same contents, so you don't lose any data anyway. If you need to introduce other operations on each file, you can put them in the loop, referring to the variables `$filename` and `$sum`, which contain the original filename and the MD5 sum respectively.

Comment: Poor habits, instilled by a long history of using sane filenames. Edited.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but explaining elements of these few lines would help me in manipulating with it and using in similar purposes. Also, right now, when your `file1 file2 file3` is replaced with `*`, it outputs `mv: target ‘ba3a926dc70c9bfee424895e278bb6d6’ is not a directory`, which makes no sense to me at this moment, since I don't know what I am looking at.

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong due to characters in the filenames. If you add `echo "$filename"; echo "$sum"` before the `mv` line, it will print the specific data that are causing the problem.

Comment: It prints all files output. I am testing this within Pictures dir, where screenshots are stored in Ubuntu, and they are all named in this fashion: `Screenshot from 2015-09-13 13:39:41.png`

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest edit of the code, with quotes around the variable expansions in the `mv` line.

Comment: Instead of piping to `xargs -0`, you can just use `find ... -exec md5sum {} +`.  Usually you only need xargs if you want to do some processing between find and xargs.  Also, `read -ra` would avoid munging backslashes in filenames.  Nice solution though: this should be faster than the obvious solution of running `md5sum` separately for every file.

Comment: @PeterCordes True on `find -exec ... +`; that may be slightly faster than `xargs`, though only slightly. I'm already using `read -r`; `-a` would wordsplit the entire line, rather than just the first two words, and so mess up filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: @TomHunt: herp derp, yeah I was mixing up `-r` and `-a`.  Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '**/*(#qD.)' '$(md5sum<$f)'
```

Would rename all the regular files, recursively.

(note that it will refuse to rename any file if two files in the same directory have the same checksum, add `-f` to override that).

`**/*(#qD.)` is `zsh`'s recursive glob with glob qualifiers (in their explicit form as `(#q<qualifiers>)`, `D` to include hidden files, `.` to only select *regular* files.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, since question's tags include `bash`....

Comment: With `bash`, you can wrap that in `zsh -c '...'`. Generally here, solutions with alternative tools are welcome as the Q&A can be useful to people with different constraints. We also see a lot of persons using the `bash` tag because they don't know other shells exist.

Comment: Fair enough. And that is an impressive bit of syntax.

Comment: @TomHunt Evidently the intent of the question was to script the task using a commonly available tool, it was not specifically about bash (and so I retagged it accordingly). It would be different if the question was actually about bash.

Answer (score 3):

bash:

```
md5sum my.file.here | { read sum filename; mv $filename $sum; }
```

Comment: How to use command for multiple files?